# resolv.conf is configured, but DNS not working

Tags: debian, dns, resolv.conf

I am stuck with DNS issue on Debian server.

My resolv.conf configuration is

```
nameserver 192.168.1.3
```

When I try to ping google.com, I have `"Temporary failure in name resolution"`.
So, I add 8.8.8.8 DNS-server to my resolv.conf config.

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 192.168.1.3
```

I can ping 8.8.8.8 host.

Now I don't have any error, but DNS server is not resolving. `Ping` or `host` commands just hang

Has anybody had such a problem? How can I troubleshoot it?

Comment: Did you add `8.8.8.8` before `192.168.1.3` or after in `/etc/resolv.conf` ?

Comment: Before. My final config is nameserver 8.8.8.8 \
nameserver 192.168.1.3

Comment: Are you behind a Corporate Firewall? Maybe it blocks DNS (udp port 53) packets? And please: Do not use Google's DNS. They do gather query-statistics for advertising purpose. Also try adding "search <yourdomain>" to the resolv.conf

Comment: If you run `nslookup 8.8.8.8 8.8.8.8` or `dig +short www.google.com @8.8.8.8` and the command just hangs until timeout, something is blocking your DNS requests to the 8.8.8.8 nameserver, or the responses coming back to you, or both. DNS is UDP + TCP, to port 53; ping is ICMP. With modern firewalls, the fact that ping works does not say anything at all about whether or not DNS should also work, and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you for response, @gerhard-d. I will contact administrator of the corporate network and ask about DNS packets. And can you, please, recommend Google DNS alternative? Cloudflare DNS will be better choice?

Comment: @telcoM you are right, nslookup 8.8.8.8 8.8.8.8 is also hanging. Thank you very much for your response. I will contact network administrator to solve the problem.

Comment: Use your companies DNS - Servers

Comment: Do not use `ping` to troubleshoot DNS problems, it is the wrong tool for thqt. Use `dig`.

Comment: "Cloudflare DNS will be better choice? "  You need to define better. There are many public recursive nameservers, with various policies on privacy, logging, QNAME minimization, etc.